# How to convert time in string format into datetime format in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

The following string was generated by this code:

myString =  12:44:44.6111472

```
myString = Date.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString
```

I want to add 16.1234567 seconds and the value of myString and assign the resulting value to a new string called myNewString.

Every function I have tried looses the 7 decimal places. 
Is there another method I can use that doesn't require me to break apart the entire string value, modify the desired parts, account for carry's, then re-assemble?

If not, then so-be-it.

But, I would like think there is some method, and I'm just not finding it!

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to read up on the precision of `DateTime`, `Single` and `Double` data types as the problem (I suspect) lies there.  You could convert the seconds part to a `Decimal` datatype, perform the addition and then put the seconds back into the `DateTime`, however I suspect the precision would be lost on that last step. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/numeric-data-types

Answer (score 0):

`Datetime` has some parsing functions that you can use.  For example:

```
    Dim mystring As String = "12:44:44.6111472"
    Dim dt As System.DateTime = System.DateTime.Parse(mystring)
    dt += New TimeSpan(16.1234567 * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)
    mystring = dt.TimeOfDay.ToString()
    'now mystring = "12:45:00.7346039"
```

Comment: Thanks Ben J,   The line with TimeSpan was the answer!

Comment: @Ken - This code doesn't compile with `Option Strict On` since it tries to convert a `Double` to a `Long`.  Try using `mystring = dt.AddTicks(CLng(16.1234567 * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)).ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach similar to Ben J's without the use of timespan (which may make things look simpler):

```
Dim myString = Date.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString

' parse datetime string and add seconds
Dim myDate = DateTime.Parse(myString).AddSeconds(16.1234567) 

' outputs 16.123000 so you still lose a few decimal points but not all 7,
' is this close enough precision for you?
Dim ts = String.Format("{0:N6}", (New TimeSpan(myDate.Ticks) - New TimeSpan(DateTime.Parse(myString).Ticks)).TotalSeconds)
```

Comment: Why convert a `DateTime` to a `string`, only to parse it back to `DateTime`?  What's the point of creating the `myString` variable at all?  Why not simply `Dim myDate = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(16.1234567))`

Comment: Good question.  I assumed OP required the input to be a string being as their question casts the variable as such.